# Can I use two classes with same names for two different targets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

There is a class A which is used in two the targets. but Class A's header and implementation is different for both targets. Can I have Class A twice? one for each target? or I have to rename one of the class and then import?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XCode - Same classe name, two targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347646/xcode-same-classe-name-two-targets)

Comment: If I add class with same name it gives error "duplicate interface defination for Class A".

Comment: why don't you name it with a different name ?

Comment: for sanity it's probably best to rename to two classes, especially if they have different implementations.

Comment: Okay. I will rename classes and use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can have "ClassA" for each target with the same name if they have different implementation. You only have to check the correct target for every "ClassA" file.