# Library tries to include <string.h> but includes "string.h" from my project, how to prevent?

Tags: c++, compilation, include, header-files, include-path

I have a `string.h` in my project added it to my header search path with `-I` (because I'm using CMake and compiling from the project root directory rather than the directory where `string.h` is located).

The project uses an external library that tries to `#include <string.h>` (the standard C header) in one of its header files that I include, and accidentally ends up including my `string.h` (because it was on the header search path that inclusion with `<>` uses).

Here's the (edited) error message that reveals this:

```
In file included from /path/to/project/src/random_source_file.cpp:3:
In file included from /usr/local/include/SDL2/SDL.h:67:
In file included from /usr/local/include/SDL2/SDL_main.h:25:
In file included from /usr/local/include/SDL2/SDL_stdinc.h:60:
In file included from /path/to/project/src/string.h:7:
etc.
```

At line 60 in `SDL_stdinc.h` there's the `#include <string.h>`.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Rename your header file :)

Comment: @George That's one solution, but a rather hacky one. :/

Comment: hack or no hack it's the sane one

Comment: If possible (your file hierarchy might make difficult) use relative include,  as in #include "/path/to/project/src/string.h"  when you want that file, use #include <string.h> (or "string.h") to reach the standard C header.  Note: not tested.

Comment: Keep the directory where your string.h is out of the header path.  Instead, put a directory above it in the header path.  Files that want to reference your string.h will need to do e.g. #include "project/src/string.h" rather than #include "string.h", but the advantage is that any code doing a naive #include "string.h" will get the standard C++ file, which is what you want.

Comment: Naming your header like a standard header does not sound like a good idea to me in the first place.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Maybe, but I'd prefer a plain "string.h" over a prefixed "mstring.h".

Comment: How about "strings.h" instead?

Comment: @JonathanPotter That's already a thing in POSIX. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/strings.h.html

Comment: "stringsesss.h" then? :)

Comment: @JonathanPotter Well inside that header is a class called "String" so a plural would sound a bit out-of-place.

Comment: @JonathanPotter "that_string_header_that_is_in_no_stupid_standard_so_far.h", just to be safe. :)

Comment: I see this as another advantage of my apparently rather unpopular style of calling my C++ headers `.hpp`. :)

Comment: @BaummitAugen True. Or `.hh`, or `String.h`. Too many possibilities…

Comment: @zenith `@George That's one solution, but a rather hacky one.`  Why is it *hacky*?  You introduced the "hack" by naming a header file the same as a standard header file (that BTW has existed since, when, the 1970's?).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Well, I mean I can have identifiers in my code hidden behind namespaces and the like to avoid clashes, surely there's something similar I can do with headers. Especially since "string" is such a common name, why should only the standard library be  entitled to have a header with that name.

Comment: @zenith The historical reason for why headers have names like this is that back in the day, C allowed a limited identifier length (I think 8 characters).   I knew this was the case with identifiers, and possibly also #include names.  If so, then there was no choice but to choose names like `string.h`, `stdio.h`, etc.  I could understand if you had created a header called `string.h`, and a later version of the standard introduced a header called `string.h`, conflicting with your existing one.  But I can't fathom an excuse for conflicting with an existing header, just for the heck of it.

Comment: Question is tagged as C++ rather than C, so why not change the library to use `<string>` rather than `<string.h>`?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Unfortunately not my library. (Also `<string>` ≠ `<string.h>`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 rules I use:

1) Include files that I have created are always included via a relative-path, and never included in an environment PATH.

```
#ifndef DTB_SUPPORT_HH
#include "../../bag/src/dtb_support.hh"
#endif
```

2) I only include Library files thru an environment PATH, and never using a relative path.

```
#include <string>
```

---

edit - origins:

My use of relative-path include grew out of the following experience:

As a contractor (one of several hundred) on a MLOC size effort, I
found cause to add a symbol to a simple file, lets call it "Foo.hh".

I used their tool to find "Foo.hh", modified it, and edited the
file I was working on to use the new symbol I put there.

During rebuild, however, the compiler complained the symbol was
unknown.

So I double checked both files, and realized there must be another
"Foo.hh".

I then lauched a build of the entire system, with option that caused the
compiler to report in the compilation output all the files that were
included for each compilation unit (I think -H?).

At first I only visited the compilation unit I was interested in,
and found the second "Foo.hh".

Curiosity got the best of me, so I grepped thru the compilation log,
and found thousands of includes of "Foo.hh".  I had to gather these
lines together, and sort them with the full path.

It turns out there were 5 paths to a "Foo.hh".  Comparing them, the 5 files were of 3 different versions.

(FYI - I removed my symbol from the 1st, added the new symbol to the 2nd, and (by direction) ignored the other 3 files.)

Comment: I ended up doing `#include <foo/string.h>` and simply `-I`ing the directory than contains `foo`. Works well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @zenith -  I hope this works for you.  To be brief above, I did not mention how many times having the relative path eased my future efforts.  On the other hand, the relative include allows (and thus encourages?) the repair or replacement or refactoring of the 3 versions of the 'duplicated' include file to be deferred into the technical debt. I think such deferment should be discouraged.