# Duplicate interface definition for class "LoginViewController" even thought they are in 2 different targets

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7, targets

I have 2 targets in my app. Only the UI changes between the targets.

1. I have a BaseLoginViewController which belong to both the targets.
2. Then I create LoginViewController.h and .m for each targets.

Even thought I have 2 LoginViewController since they are in 2 different targets it should not create any problem.

But sometimes when i check out and build, Xcode gives me **Duplicate interface definition for class "LoginViewController"**. If i delete the LoginViewController and add them again the error used to disappear.

But now even that a'int working. :(

I have so many other classes which uses this approach but none of them gives me this problem. Also this problem is there only in one of the targets.

Comment: First idea: make sure that there aren't any duplicates in the build-phases of the two targets.

Comment: @TMob i had checked that already forgot to mention no duplicates in both the targets.

Comment: How are the files separated on the file-system? Maybe take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2598519/3981769