# Include paths not excluding user path for static lib project

Tags: c++, xcode

Make new library project in Xcode (8.3.2), choose Framework: STL (C++ Library), Type: **Static**, and name it "MyLibrary". You'll get starting files MyLibrary.hpp, MyLibraryPriv.hpp, MyLibrary.cpp. Create new header file, semaphore.h, an place it with in the same folder as all the others. This file should have an include guard definition `semaphore_h`.

Add in MyLibrary.cpp the following lines:

```
#include <semaphore.h>

#ifdef _BSD_SEMAPHORE_H
#warning _BSD_SEMAPHORE_H
#endif

#ifdef semaphore_h
#warning semaphore_h
#endif
```

I am including here a system header file, not the file I just added, but the result of the build is that `semaphore_h` will be written as a build warning, which is wrong. If I rename my file in Finder then `_BSD_SEMAPHORE_H` is written, as it should be.

Is this a bug? How to workaround it? I have a header in my project that shares the same name as a system header, but I would rather not change the name.

Strange thing is, if it were an **app** project (Command Line Tool) then it would work as expected. `#include <semaphore.h>` would cause `_BSD_SEMAPHORE_H` warning and `#include "semaphore.h"` would cause `semaphore_h` warning. Library project behaves differently than app project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it's a bug stretching to Xcode 4 and probably beyond. Build option USE_HEADERMAP should be disabled for static libraries (Project settings > Search Paths > Use Header Maps > set to **No**). Then there should be no collisions between header files of the same name.

The option does not cause problems for apps, though it apparently used to in the [past](http://www.crickettechnology.com/blog/?p=671). There's also a SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2596695) for which disabling the option is the answer, but when I read it for the first time I did not realize it applies to my case as well.